# Did Java's default access modifier used to be public

Tags: java, access-modifiers

Back in 2004, when I took an intro to CS course at RIT, my professor stressed really hard about us remembering to put in access modifiers.  Without it, the default access would be public, is what I remember the professor saying.  Maybe my memory is wrong, and the professor didn't actually say it, but clearly that isn't the case now.  I am wondering if that used to be the case at some point though and maybe Sun changed it at some point post-2004?

Comment: If you are talking about the access modifier on method in interfaces, it is still true.

Comment: you have a long memory :)

Comment: Going back even further to [Oak 0.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oak_%28programming_language%29) the spec even says [the following](http://aioo.be/mirrored/OakSpec0.2.pdf): "By default all variables and methods in a class (including constructors) are
private." That was more than 10 years earlier though :-) The current scopes is clearly visualized in [this table](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33627846/276052).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java classes without access modifiers have been package-private since Java 1.0.

Here is a link to the applicable section of the [JLS 1.0](http://titanium.cs.berkeley.edu/doc/java-langspec-1.0/6.doc.html#33916):

> If a class or interface type is declared public, then it may be accessed by any Java code that can access the package in which it is declared. If a class or interface type is not declared public, then it may be accessed only from within the package in which it is declared.

For members inside types, it says:

> A member (field or method) of a reference (class, interface, or array)
>   type or a constructor of a class type is accessible only if the type
>   is accessible and the member or constructor is declared to permit
>   access:
>
> - If the member or constructor is declared public, then access is
>     permitted. All members of interfaces are implicitly public.
> - Otherwise, if the member or constructor is declared protected, then
>     access is permitted only when one of the following is true:
>
>   - Access to the member or constructor occurs from within the package containing the class in which the protected member is
>       declared.
>   - Access occurs within a subclass of the class in which the protected member is declared, and the access is correct as described
>       in §6.6.2.
> - Otherwise, if the member or constructor is declared
>     private, then access is permitted only when it occurs from within the
>     class in which it is declared.
> - Otherwise, we say there is default
>     access, which is permitted only when the access occurs from within the
>     package in which the type is declared.

Which means that if left without a modifier, a member/constructor of a class would be package-private, not public.

Members of interfaces, though, are never anything other than `public`, so applying access modifiers to them won't change a thing (well, if you try `private` or `protected` you'll get a compilation error), so whatever the you remember the professor saying, it doesn't apply to interfaces.

Answer (score 6):

On classes, default access is package-private. On interfaces the default for members is public, while the default for the interface itself, like classes, is package-private.

It hasn't changed since Java was released.

Comment: @RealSkeptic The interface *itself*, true, but for the *members* of the interface, the default is `public`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Including your comment, which is why I clarified it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The default access specifier is package-private for a class since start. From the [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html):

> If a class has no modifier (the default, also known as
>   package-private), it is visible only within its own package (packages
>   are named groups of related classes — you will learn about them in a
>   later lesson.)
>
> At the member level, you can also use the public modifier or no
>   modifier (package-private) just as with top-level classes, and with
>   the same meaning. For members, there are two additional access
>   modifiers: private and protected. The private modifier specifies that
>   the member can only be accessed in its own class. The protected
>   modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed within its own
>   package (as with package-private) and, in addition, by a subclass of
>   its class in another package.